# JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator

I am getting the following error screen every time I'm scrolling or navigating the app when I reload my React Native app in iOS Simulator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVwsF.png)

I'm not sure what could be the reason for this error.

I thought it could potentially be something wrong with the source of my images but don't think that's the issue.

```
const UserItem = (props: { onSelect: () => void, user: User }) => {

return <AccountContainer onPress={props.onSelect}>
    <AccountImage source={{ uri: props.user.photoUrl }} />
    <Text text={props.user.username} />
</AccountContainer>
```

}

I'm also making sure I strinfiy the json objects as I've seen people had this same issue with AsyncStorage

```
const save = async <T>(key: string, value: T): Promise<T | null> => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    return value;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the same error by calling `AsyncStorage.setItem(null, "#");`

You can wrap up the `setItem` call so it won't throw a native error.

```
const safeSetStorageItem = (key: string, value: object) => {
  if (!key) {
    logger.warn("Probably a mistake here...raise a warning and investigate");
    return;
  }

  return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
};
```

Comment: I've currently wrapped it in a try, catch

Comment: Yes, it's effectively the same, except the try/catch will catch any other errors that might crop up.